# How to communicate between activity to fragment in navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation

In Navigation drawer ,activity1 and fragment1 both are present in MainActivity (Main activity of navigation drawer).
I want to know how to go from activity1 to fragment1 in this case?

Comment: please paste your code

Comment: what you had done so far ? You should post some code here

Answer (score 1):

If you are in activity 1 and want to load navigation drawer fragments then you can use back button to come back to MainActivity then load fragment from the navigation drawer. But if want to replace fragment from activity 1 then you can use this

```
Fragment var_fragment = new Fragment1();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, var_fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

but if you want to add fragment to the activity1 then use transaction.add(...);

Refer this tutorial to load fragment or activity in navigation drawer
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/